# React JS Dynamic Form onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have an dynamic created fields (input tag)

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ native: [{}], rolls: [{}] }) // initial data

{navtive?.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        name={item.id}
        onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange("fee", e.target.value, index, item.id)
        }
        />
...
{rolls?.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        name={item.id}
        onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange("fee", e.target.value, index, item.id)
        }
        />
```

Expected Output:

```
const output = {
    native: [{id: 1, fee: "12"}, {id: 5, fee: "2"}],
    rolls: [{id: 4, fee: "1332"}],
};
```

onChange function :

```
const handleChange = (field, value, index) => {
    setData((prevState) => {
        const nextState = [...prevState];
        nextState[index][field] = value;
        return nextState;
    });
};
```

How to get the expected output ? What am I making wrong in the onChange function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am Reproduced with one one example and I add some comment lines

codeSandBox :https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-bash-lrvkc?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);

  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);
  };

  // CHANGE HERE: a flag to be set when there is an error

  const Submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(inputList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box">
            <div>
              <input
                name="firstName"
                placeholder="Enter First Name"
                value={x.firstName}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                className="ml10"
                name="lastName"
                placeholder="Enter Last Name"
                value={x.lastName}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="btn-box">
              {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                <button className="mr10" onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
              {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={Submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nice code snippet, It's helpful to also leave a brief explanation of the solution in words as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).